# php script to scrape emails for appointments and generate a .ics file to be emailed to relevant User for easy scheduling

Tags: php, email, icalendar, postfix-mta

I work in a business where we have a hosted CRM which sends out jobsheets we are trying to code a script in php which emails us calendar entries for jobs assigned to us currently the code (below) scrapes our email and emails us a .ics but it's output while a valid .ics file (we can manually import them) doesn't appear in the email as an acceptable invite so we can simply accept the entry Advice & codesnippets appreciated

--Original code--

```
$mbox=FALSE;
$imap_username="User@tbclaunceston.com.au";
$imap_password="Password";

$connection="{".$server.":".$port."}".$path;
$mbox=imap_open($connection, $imap_username, $imap_password);
$messages=imap_search($mbox, 'UNSEEN SUBJECT "Commtrak: Job Card"');
foreach($messages as $message){
//var_dump(imap_header($mbox,$message));
$bodynormal = imap_body($mbox,$message);
$body = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",strip_tags($bodynormal));

$to = $imap_username;       
$subjectsearch = array("Company Name:","Job ID:");
    $subject = locatedata($body,"Company Name:","Job ID:");

    $organizer = 'CommTrak';
    $organizer_email = 'testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au';

    $participant_name_1 = 'User';
    $participant_email_1= $imap_username;
if(strpos($body,"Sales Contact:")!=false){
    $search = "Sales Contact:";
}
else{
    $search = "Customer Contact:";
}
if(locatedata($body,"Site Address:",$search)=="As Above"){
        $location = locatedata($body,"Customer Address:","Site Address:");
}
else{
    $location = locatedata($body,"Site Address:",$search);
}
$date = "20".implode('', array_reverse(explode("/",locatedata($body,"Date:","Time:"))));
$startTime = locatedata($body,"Time:","For:");
$endTime = date("H:i",strtotime($startTime." +".str_replace("hrs","hours",locatedata($body,"For:","JOB DESCRIPTION:"))));
$startTime = str_replace(":","",$startTime);
$endTime = str_replace(":","",$endTime);
    $desc = locatedata($body,"JOB DESCRIPTION:","CO Number:");
$headers = "From: CommTrak Jobs <testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au>\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; name=jobcard.ics; method=REQUEST\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename='jobcard.ics'\r\n";
//$headers .= "Content-class','urn:content-classes:calendarmessage";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";

$message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nPRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:Tasmania Standard Time\r\nBEGIN:STANDARD\r\nDTSTART:16010101T030000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+1100\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+1000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4\r\nEND:STANDARD\r\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+1000\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+1100\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=10\r\nEND:DAYLIGHT\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."\r\nATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=".$participant_name_1.":MAILTO:".$participant_email_1."\r\nDESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$desc."\r\nUID:".md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true))."tbclaunceston.com.au\r\nSUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$subject."\r\nDTSTART;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':".$date."T".$startTime."00\r\nDTEND;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':".$date."T".$endTime."00\r\nCLASS:PUBLIC\r\nPRIORITY:5\r\nDTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd').'T'.gmdate('His')."Z\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nLOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$location."\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:1787906015\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nDESCRIPTION:REMINDER\r\nTRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M\r\nACTION:DISPLAY\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";
//$headers .= $message;
$message = base64_encode($message);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
break;
//echo $message."\r\n***********************\r\n";   
}
?>
```

--Current Code Iteration

```
$connection="{".$server.":".$port."}".$path;
$mbox=imap_open($connection, $imap_username, $imap_password);
$messages=imap_search($mbox, 'UNSEEN SUBJECT "Commtrak: Job Card"');
foreach($messages as $message){
    //var_dump(imap_header($mbox,$message));
    $boundary=uniqid("np");
    $bodynormal = imap_body($mbox,$message);
    $body = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",strip_tags($bodynormal));

    //$to = $imap_username;
    $to = "testaccount@gmail.com";      
    $subjectsearch = array("Company Name:","Job ID:");
        $subject = locatedata($body,"Company Name:","Job ID:");

        $organizer = 'CommTrak';
        $organizer_email = 'testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au';

        $participant_name_1 = 'a User';
        $participant_email_1= $imap_username;
    if(strpos($body,"Sales Contact:")!=false){
        $search = "Sales Contact:";
    }
    else{
        $search = "Customer Contact:";
    }
    if(locatedata($body,"Site Address:",$search)=="As Above"){
            $location = locatedata($body,"Customer Address:","Site Address:");
    }
    else{
        $location = locatedata($body,"Site Address:",$search);
    }
    $date = "20".implode('', array_reverse(explode("/",locatedata($body,"Date:","Time:"))));
    $startTime = locatedata($body,"Time:","For:");
    $endTime = date("H:i",strtotime($startTime." +".str_replace("hrs","hours",locatedata($body,"For:","JOB DESCRIPTION:"))));
    $startTime = str_replace(":","",$startTime);
    $endTime = str_replace(":","",$endTime);
        $desc = locatedata($body,"JOB DESCRIPTION:","CO Number:");
    $headers = "From: CommTrak Jobs <testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au>\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "To:".$to."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary=".$boundary."\r\n\r\n--".$boundary."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; name=jobcard.ics; method=REQUEST\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename='jobcard.ics'\r\n";
    //$headers .= "Content-class','urn:content-classes:calendarmessage";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;
    //boundary=".$boundary."\r\n";

    $message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nPRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:Tasmania Standard Time\r\nBEGIN:STANDARD\r\nDTSTART:16010101T030000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+1100\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+1000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4\r\nEND:STANDARD\r\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\nDTSTART:16010101T020000\r\nTZOFFSETFROM:+1000\r\nTZOFFSETTO:+1100\r\nRRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=10\r\nEND:DAYLIGHT\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."\r\nATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=".$participant_name_1.":MAILTO:".$participant_email_1."\r\nDESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$desc."\r\nUID:".md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true))."tbclaunceston.com.au\r\nSUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$subject."\r\nDTSTART;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':".$date."T".$startTime."00\r\nDTEND;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':".$date."T".$endTime."00\r\nCLASS:PUBLIC\r\nPRIORITY:5\r\nDTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd').'T'.gmdate('His')."Z\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nLOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:".$location."\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:1787906015\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\nX-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0\r\nX-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\r\nBEGIN:VALARM\r\nDESCRIPTION:REMINDER\r\nTRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M\r\nACTION:DISPLAY\r\nEND:VALARM\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    //$message = base64_encode($message);
    $message .= "\r\n\r\n--".$boundary."\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    break;
    //echo $message."\r\n***********************\r\n";   
}
?>
```

--Resultant Message output

```
Delivered-To: testaccount@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.163.3 with SMTP id j3csp923632qhj;
    Tue, 21 Apr 2015 17:26:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.68.111.35 with SMTP id if3mr38633671pbb.70.1429662408016;
        Tue, 21 Apr 2015 17:26:48 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <root@tclp-28.localdomain>
Received: from tclp-28.localdomain (totalc92.lnk.telstra.net. [120.151.44.165])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id u7si5131112pbs.1.2015.04.21.17.26.47
        for <testaccount@gmail.com>;
        Tue, 21 Apr 2015 17:26:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: root@tclp-28.localdomain does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=120.151.44.165;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=none (google.com: root@tclp-28.localdomain does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=root@tclp-28.localdomain
Received: by tclp-28.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 8C7EED40968; Wed, 22 Apr 2015 10:26:45 +1000 (AEST)
To: testaccount@gmail.com
Subject: ROBERT FINDLAY
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:ICSconverter3.php
From: CommTrak Jobs <testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au>
MIME-Version: 1.0
To:testaccount@gmail.com
Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary=np5536eac52d6fe
Message-Id: <20150422002645.8C7EED40968@tclp-28.localdomain>
Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 10:26:45 +1000 (AEST)

--np5536eac52d6fe
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; name=jobcard.ics; method=REQUEST
Content-Disposition: inline; filename='jobcard.ics'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;
        //boundary=np5536eac52d6fe

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Tasmania Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=CommTrak:mailto:testaccount1@tbclaunceston.com.au
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=a User:MAILTO:testaccount@tbclaunceston.com.au
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:On site set-up for office 365. installing accounts/products on devices
UID:c1cb622dd0d1ecdc9e93f778d0b7964atbclaunceston.com.au
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Agent Smith
DTSTART;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':20150424T-00
DTEND;TZID='Tasmania Standard Time':20150424T100000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20150422T002645Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:123 some where RD
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:1787906015
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


--np5536eac52d6fe
```

Comment: okay have realised i may have been a little unclear client for the email is outlook 2013 and we want the .ics file to come in as a calendar invite

Comment: What you really want to show us is the resulting MIME message and iCalendar stream that is received on the client side.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion arnaudq. have added the current iteration of code (minor changes) and the resultant message, I have sanitized the email addresses and names throughout otherwise this is as we have it, Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a multipart/alternative containing only the text/calendar part which is OK but not very useful.
Then you have a content-transfer-encoding when in fact your body part is not b64 encoded.
You also  have this strange comment line after the last header ("        //boundary=np5536eac52d6fe").

Finally, your DTSTART is invalid: "20150424T-00"

Comment: Thanks for the pickup on DTSTART the non encoding to base64 was just for here, its present but commented out for ease of the ics debug